# Visual Studio 17.3 warnings don't make sense

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Visual Studio tries to give me directions on what mistakes I might be making.
Very nice, but with each update, more warnings appear I can't make heads or tails of.
Look at the warning below:
[image]

Each and every reference to some item (variable, function) gets a red underlining with these warnings. "Not null"? I hope so! "Ambiguity"? With what? Itself?

Options? (And no, better not disabling the warnings. I don't want to miss real mistakes)

Comment: Which language? C#?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/nullable-warnings - its a brave new world. You can sprinkle null-forgiving operators around your code and generally try to live with it (and understand it better). Or disable the warnings or just don't use this feature :) It seems that UI code is not always so amenable to nullable reference types because some values are populated automagically during load operations and page rendering etc. and so won't be null at runtime, but the compiler can't figure all that out yet.

Comment: I don't really see the ambiguity. You could try adding `this.dataGridView1` and see what happens (although usually in C# you don't need that). Possibly more context will be needed to figure that out.

Comment: @topsail Thanks for the reference. I do understand the need for warnings when a referenced item **is/could be** null. What I don't understand that is warns me the item **is not** null.

Comment: @topsail adding `this` (or `frmEventlog` for that matter), doesn't change anything.

Comment: Its a strange message - you want to ask VS *"who said anything about this being null here?"*. I don't think its even a warning. I guess it's just "information".

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found some weird "conflicted copies" of the designer.cs files.
After deleting them, all warnings disappeared except the obvious ones like
[image]

Constructs like `is not null` don't change it.